# ParamInitializer framework: automatic provision of expected request parameters by Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I continue to share portions of my [Dynamic Gateway project](https://github.com/NadChel/dynamic-gateway)

This time, I want to publish the types relating to its "parameter initializing" functionality. The idea is simple: if my gateway notices that a discovered Swagger endpoint of another service expects, say, `param-one`, and it has a `ParamInitializer` that is capable of providing a such a parameter, the gateway asks the `ParamInitializer` to "initialize" the param by adding a `GatewayFilter` to the `Route` associated with the endpoint. I have two `ParamInitializer`s that initialize `principal` and `roles` parameters with the principal's name and the authorities respectively. So any service connected to the same Eureka server as my gateway can simply declare an endpoint accepting parameter `principal` and the name of the principal will be automatically provided for that endpoint (in fact, it can even do that in the gateway's runtime, but that's beyond the point of this post)

However, there's still a *feeling* that I do something wrong. That feeling isn't going away no matter how much I refactor. I can't pinpoint it exactly. Maybe I do some wheel reinvention or take a fundamentally flawed approach to achieve my goal. I have no idea. Maybe it's just part of my overall self-doubt, and it's actually fine

Anyway, I'm looking forward to your feedback

***Note.** I tried to include all the necessary parts, but I can't rule out that I accidentally missed something. It's part of a much bigger project after all. Please let me know if I did fail to include some types or dependencies.*

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.util.GatewayFilterUtil;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

/**
 * A supplier of {@link ParamInitializingGatewayFilter}s that could be added to {@link Route} builders
 */
public interface ParamInitializer {

    /**
     * Wraps the parameter initializing filter returned by {@link ParamInitializer#initializingFilter()}
     * in a new {@link OrderedGatewayFilter} with the order of zero and then adds it to
     * the passed-in {@code Route} builder
     *
     * @param routeInConstruction a {@code Route} builder to which the filter should be added
     * @see GatewayFilterUtil#wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(GatewayFilter, int)
     */
    default void addInitializingFilter(Route.AbstractBuilder<?> routeInConstruction) {
        GatewayFilter initializingFilterWrapper =
                GatewayFilterUtil.wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(initializingFilter());
        routeInConstruction.filter(initializingFilterWrapper);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@link ParamInitializingGatewayFilter} that adds to the request
     * {@link Object#toString() string representations} of parameter values published
     * by the {@code Flux} returned by {@link ParamInitializer#getParamValues(ServerWebExchange)}.
     * The values are associated with the key returned by {@link ParamInitializer#getParamName()}
     */
    default ParamInitializingGatewayFilter initializingFilter() {
        return new ParamInitializingGatewayFilter(
                getParamName(),
                this::getParamValues,
                getParamStrategy());
    }

    String getParamName();

    Flux<?> getParamValues(ServerWebExchange exchange);

    ParamInitializingStrategy getParamStrategy();
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter.EndpointParameter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * A wrapper around a {@code Map} of request parameter names to {@link ParamInitializer}s
 * that are capable of providing such parameters
 */
@Component
public class ParamInitializers {
    private final Map<String, ParamInitializer> paramToParamInitializerMap;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of {@code ParamInitializers} from a {@code List} of
     * provided {@code ParamInitializer}s. Note that in case more than one {@code ParamInitializer}
     * handles a given parameter, say {@code "param-one"}, only the last handler of that parameter
     * in the list will be returned by {@code findInitializerForParam("param-one")}
     */
    public ParamInitializers(List<ParamInitializer> paramInitializers) {
        HashMap<String, ParamInitializer> paramToParamInitializerMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (ParamInitializer paramInitializer : paramInitializers) {
            paramToParamInitializerMap.put(paramInitializer.getParamName(), paramInitializer);
        }
        this.paramToParamInitializerMap = paramToParamInitializerMap;
    }

    /**
     * A shorthand for {@code findInitializerForParam(endpointParameter.getName())}
     *
     * @see ParamInitializers#findInitializerForParam(String)
     */
    public Optional<ParamInitializer> findInitializerForParam(EndpointParameter param) {
        return findInitializerForParam(param.getName());
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to find a {@code ParamInitializer} handling the provided parameter
     *
     * @param paramName the name of a request parameter
     * @return an {@code Optional} of a {@code ParamInitializer} whose {@link ParamInitializer#getParamName()}
     * equals the passed-in parameter name (considering case); if such a {@code ParamInitializer}
     * wasn't found among injected {@code ParamInitializer}s, the method returns an empty {@code Optional}
     */
    public Optional<ParamInitializer> findInitializerForParam(String paramName) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(paramToParamInitializerMap.get(paramName));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * A {@link GatewayFilter} that adds parameters to requests received by this Gateway
 * according to the injected {@link ParamInitializingStrategy strategy}
 */
public class ParamInitializingGatewayFilter implements GatewayFilter {
    private final String paramName;
    private final Function<ServerWebExchange, Flux<?>> paramValuesFunction;
    private final ParamInitializingStrategy strategy;

    /**
     * @param paramName           the name of a request parameter
     * @param paramValuesFunction a way to retrieve a {@code Flux} of
     *                            parameter values from the exchange
     * @param strategy            a strategy to add the parameters to the request's query map
     */
    public ParamInitializingGatewayFilter(String paramName,
                                          Function<ServerWebExchange, Flux<?>> paramValuesFunction,
                                          ParamInitializingStrategy strategy) {
        this.paramName = paramName;
        this.paramValuesFunction = paramValuesFunction;
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    /**
     * Applies the injected {@code paramValuesFunction} on the exchange, adds the parameters
     * published by the resulting {@code Flux} to the request, then filters the exchange further
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return paramValuesFunction.apply(exchange)
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collectList()
                .flatMap(paramValues -> changeExchangeAndFilter(exchange, chain, paramValues));
    }

    private Mono<Void> changeExchangeAndFilter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain,
                                               List<String> paramValues) {
        ServerWebExchange newExchange = buildNewExchange(exchange, paramValues);
        return chain.filter(newExchange);
    }

    private ServerWebExchange buildNewExchange(ServerWebExchange exchange, List<String> paramValues) {
        ServerHttpRequest newRequest = buildNewRequest(exchange.getRequest(), paramValues);
        return exchange
                .mutate()
                .request(newRequest)
                .build();
    }

    private ServerHttpRequest buildNewRequest(ServerHttpRequest request, List<String> paramValues) {
        URI newUri = buildNewUri(request, paramValues);
        return request
                .mutate()
                .uri(newUri)
                .build();
    }

    private URI buildNewUri(ServerHttpRequest request, List<String> paramValues) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> oldQueryMap = request.getQueryParams();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> newQueryMap =
                strategy.apply(oldQueryMap, paramName, paramValues);
        return UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUri(request.getURI())
                .replaceQueryParams(newQueryMap)
                .build()
                .toUri();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * A strategy for mutating query parameter maps
 */
public enum ParamInitializingStrategy {
    /**
     * A strategy that always replaces old parameter values with new values
     */
    REPLACE_PARAMS_ALWAYS {
        @Override
        MultiValueMap<String, String> apply(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
            return queryMapWithReplacedParams(queryMap, paramName, newParamValues);
        }
    },
    /**
     * A strategy that replaces old parameter values with new values, but only if
     * no parameter value is already associated with the parameter name key
     */
    REPLACE_PARAMS_IF_ABSENT {
        @Override
        MultiValueMap<String, String> apply(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
            List<String> currentParamValues = queryMap.get(paramName);
            return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(currentParamValues) ?
                    queryMapWithReplacedParams(queryMap, paramName, newParamValues) :
                    queryMap;
        }
    },
    /**
     * A strategy that always adds provided parameter values to those already associated
     * with the parameter name key (if any)
     */
    APPEND_PARAMS_ALWAYS {
        @Override
        MultiValueMap<String, String> apply(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
            return queryMapWithAppendedParams(queryMap, paramName, newParamValues);
        }
    },
    /**
     * A strategy that adds provided parameter values to the query map, but only if
     * no parameter value is already associated with the parameter name key
     */
    APPEND_PARAMS_IF_ABSENT {
        @Override
        MultiValueMap<String, String> apply(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
            List<String> currentParamValues = queryMap.get(paramName);
            return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(currentParamValues) ?
                    queryMapWithAppendedParams(queryMap, paramName, newParamValues) :
                    queryMap;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Applies this strategy
     *
     * @param queryMap       a map of request parameter names to associated parameter values
     * @param paramName      the name of a parameter
     * @param newParamValues new values for the parameter
     * @return a query map, potentially enriched with new parameter values
     */
    abstract MultiValueMap<String, String> apply(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                                 String paramName, List<String> newParamValues);

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMapWithReplacedParams(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
        return queryMapWithNewParamValues(queryMap, paramName, newParamValues);
    }

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMapWithAppendedParams(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
        List<String> currentParamValues = queryMap.get(paramName);
        List<String> aggregatedParamValues = Stream.concat(
                        currentParamValues.stream(),
                        newParamValues.stream())
                .toList();
        return queryMapWithNewParamValues(queryMap, paramName, aggregatedParamValues);
    }

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMapWithNewParamValues(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap,
                                                                            String paramName, List<String> newParamValues) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> writableQueryMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(queryMap);
        writableQueryMap.put(paramName, newParamValues);
        return writableQueryMap;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

/**
 * A {@link ParamInitializer} that employs the {@link ParamInitializingStrategy#REPLACE_PARAMS_ALWAYS} strategy
 */
public abstract class ReplacingParamInitializer implements ParamInitializer {
    @Override
    public ParamInitializingStrategy getParamStrategy() {
        return ParamInitializingStrategy.REPLACE_PARAMS_ALWAYS;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.util;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.PrefixPathGatewayFilterFactory;

public class GatewayFilterUtil {
    /**
     * A shorthand for {@code GatewayFilterUtil.wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(gatewayFilter, 0)}
     *
     * @see GatewayFilterUtil#wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(GatewayFilter, int)
     */
    public static GatewayFilter wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(GatewayFilter wrappee) {
        return wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(wrappee, 0);
    }
    /**
     * Wraps the passed {@link GatewayFilter} in an instance of {@link OrderedGatewayFilter}.
     * At the point of this writing, some filters, such as the one produced by a
     * {@link PrefixPathGatewayFilterFactory}, may not work unless wrapped in such a way
     *
     * @param wrappee a filter to wrap
     * @return an {@code OrderedGatewayFilter} with the specified order
     */
    public static GatewayFilter wrapInOrderedGatewayFilter(GatewayFilter wrappee, int order) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter(wrappee, order);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter;

// I have a simple implementation, but I believe it's unnecessary to include it
public interface EndpointParameter {
    String getName();

    boolean isRequired();
}
```

*(it's not StackOverflow, I can paste the entire POM, right, no MRE rules?)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress VulnerableLibrariesLocal -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamic-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dynamic-gateway</name>
    <description>dynamic-gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.11.5</jsonwebtoken.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.jqno.equalsverifier</groupId>
            <artifactId>equalsverifier</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.95</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.95</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                            <maximum>0</maximum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Exception.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/DynamicGatewayApplication.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## Tests

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.testUtil.RouteBuilderUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assumptions.assumeThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

class ReplacingParamInitializerTest {
    private final List<Integer> testParamValues = List.of(1, 2, 3);
    private final Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder = Route.async();
    private final ParamInitializer paramInitializer = new ReplacingParamInitializer() {
        @Override
        public String getParamName() {
            return "param";
        }

        @Override
        public Flux<?> getParamValues(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
            return Flux.fromIterable(testParamValues);
        }
    };

    @Test
    void whenInitializeInvoked_filterAdded() {
        assumeThat(RouteBuilderUtil.getFilters(routeBuilder)).isEmpty();

        paramInitializer.addInitializingFilter(routeBuilder);

        List<GatewayFilter> filters = RouteBuilderUtil.getFilters(routeBuilder);
        assertThat(filters).hasSize(1);
    }

    @Test
    void whenInitializeInvoked_filterCorrect() {
        assumeThat(RouteBuilderUtil.getFilters(routeBuilder)).asList().isEmpty();

        paramInitializer.addInitializingFilter(routeBuilder);

        List<GatewayFilter> filters = RouteBuilderUtil.getFilters(routeBuilder);
        assumeThat(filters).asList().hasSize(1);

        assertFilterReplacesOldParamsOfName(filters.get(0));
    }

    private void assertFilterReplacesOldParamsOfName(GatewayFilter filter) {
        MockServerHttpRequest requestMock = MockServerHttpRequest.get("/test-path")
                .queryParam(paramInitializer.getParamName(), 
                        "these", "values", "should", "be", "replaced")
                .build();

        ServerWebExchange exchangeMock = MockServerWebExchange.from(requestMock);

        ArgumentCaptor<ServerWebExchange> exchangeCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServerWebExchange.class);

        GatewayFilterChain chainMock = mock(GatewayFilterChain.class);
        given(chainMock.filter(any())).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(exchangeMock, chainMock))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();

        then(chainMock).should().filter(exchangeCaptor.capture());

        List<String> actualParamValues = exchangeCaptor.getValue()
                .getRequest()
                .getQueryParams()
                .get(paramInitializer.getParamName());
        List<String> expectedParamValues = testParamValues.stream()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .toList();
        assertThat(actualParamValues)
                .asList()
                .containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(expectedParamValues);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class ParamInitializingStrategyTest {
    @Test
    void replaceParamAlways_ifParamsAbsent_replacesParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.REPLACE_PARAMS_ALWAYS)
                .withAbsentInitialParamsOfName()
                .replacesParams();
    }

    @Test
    void replaceParamAlways_ifParamsPresent_replacesParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.REPLACE_PARAMS_ALWAYS)
                .withPresentInitialParamsOfName()
                .replacesParams();
    }

    @Test
    void replaceParamIfAbsent_ifAbsent_replacesParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.REPLACE_PARAMS_IF_ABSENT)
                .withAbsentInitialParamsOfName()
                .replacesParams();
    }

    @Test
    void replaceParamIfAbsent_ifPresent_keepsOldParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.REPLACE_PARAMS_IF_ABSENT)
                .withPresentInitialParamsOfName()
                .keepsOldParams();
    }

    @Test
    void appendParamsAlways_ifParamsAbsent_appendsParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.APPEND_PARAMS_ALWAYS)
                .withAbsentInitialParamsOfName()
                .appendsParams();
    }

    @Test
    void appendParamsAlways_ifParamsPresent_appendsParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.APPEND_PARAMS_ALWAYS)
                .withPresentInitialParamsOfName()
                .appendsParams();
    }

    @Test
    void appendParamsIfAbsent_ifParamsAbsent_appendsParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.APPEND_PARAMS_IF_ABSENT)
                .withAbsentInitialParamsOfName()
                .appendsParams();
    }

    @Test
    void appendParamsIfAbsent_ifParamsPresent_keepsOldParams() {
        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert
                .assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy.APPEND_PARAMS_IF_ABSENT)
                .withPresentInitialParamsOfName()
                .keepsOldParams();
    }

    private static class ParamInitializingStrategyAssert {
        private final ParamInitializingStrategy testedStrategy;
        private List<String> initialParams = Collections.emptyList();
        private Expectation behaviorExpectation = Expectation.KEEPING_OLD_PARAMS;

        private ParamInitializingStrategyAssert(ParamInitializingStrategy testedStrategy) {
            this.testedStrategy = testedStrategy;
        }

        static ParamInitializingStrategyAssert assertThatStrategy(ParamInitializingStrategy testedStrategy) {
            return new ParamInitializingStrategyAssert(testedStrategy);
        }

        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert withAbsentInitialParamsOfName() {
            this.initialParams = Collections.emptyList();
            return this;
        }

        ParamInitializingStrategyAssert withPresentInitialParamsOfName() {
            this.initialParams = List.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            return this;
        }

        void replacesParams() {
            this.behaviorExpectation = Expectation.REPLACEMENT;
            assertStrategyBehavior();
        }

        void appendsParams() {
            this.behaviorExpectation = Expectation.APPENDING;
            assertStrategyBehavior();
        }

        void keepsOldParams() {
            this.behaviorExpectation = Expectation.KEEPING_OLD_PARAMS;
            assertStrategyBehavior();
        }

        void assertStrategyBehavior() {
            String paramName = "param";
            MultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(Map.of(
                    paramName, initialParams
            ));
            List<String> newParams = List.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            MultiValueMap<String, String> newQueryMap = testedStrategy.apply(queryMap, paramName, newParams);
            List<String> expectedParamValues =
                    behaviorExpectation.getExpectedParamValues(initialParams, newParams);
            assertThat(newQueryMap.get(paramName))
                    .containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(expectedParamValues);
        }

        private enum Expectation {
            REPLACEMENT {
                @Override
                List<String> getExpectedParamValues(List<String> initialParamValues,
                                                    List<String> newParamValues) {
                    return newParamValues;
                }
            }, APPENDING {
                @Override
                List<String> getExpectedParamValues(List<String> initialParamValues,
                                                    List<String> newParamValues) {
                    return Stream.concat(initialParamValues.stream(),
                                    newParamValues.stream())
                            .toList();
                }
            },
            KEEPING_OLD_PARAMS {
                @Override
                List<String> getExpectedParamValues(List<String> initialParamValues,
                                                    List<String> newParamValues) {
                    return initialParamValues;
                }
            };

            abstract List<String> getExpectedParamValues(List<String> initialParams,
                                                         List<String> newParams);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer;

import com.example.dynamicgateway.model.endpointParameter.EndpointParameter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

class ParamInitializersTest {
    @Test
    void findInitializerForParam_withSupportedParam() {
        ParamInitializer paramOneInitializerMock = mock(ParamInitializer.class);
        given(paramOneInitializerMock.getParamName()).willReturn("paramOne");

        ParamInitializer paramTwoInitializerMock = mock(ParamInitializer.class);
        given(paramTwoInitializerMock.getParamName()).willReturn("paramTwo");

        List<ParamInitializer> testParamInitializers = List.of(
                paramOneInitializerMock, paramTwoInitializerMock
        );

        EndpointParameter paramOneMock = mock(EndpointParameter.class);
        given(paramOneMock.getName()).willReturn("paramOne");

        ParamInitializers paramInitializers = new ParamInitializers(testParamInitializers);
        Optional<ParamInitializer> initializerForParam = paramInitializers.findInitializerForParam(paramOneMock);
        assertThat(initializerForParam).isPresent();
        assertThat(initializerForParam.orElseThrow()).isEqualTo(paramOneInitializerMock);
    }

    @Test
    void findInitializerForParam_withNonSupportedParam() {
        ParamInitializer paramOneInitializerMock = mock(ParamInitializer.class);
        given(paramOneInitializerMock.getParamName()).willReturn("paramOne");

        ParamInitializer paramTwoInitializerMock = mock(ParamInitializer.class);
        given(paramTwoInitializerMock.getParamName()).willReturn("paramTwo");

        List<ParamInitializer> testParamInitializers = List.of(
                paramOneInitializerMock, paramTwoInitializerMock
        );

        EndpointParameter paramOneMock = mock(EndpointParameter.class);
        given(paramOneMock.getName()).willReturn("paramThree");

        ParamInitializers paramInitializers = new ParamInitializers(testParamInitializers);
        Optional<ParamInitializer> initializerForParam = paramInitializers.findInitializerForParam(paramOneMock);
        assertThat(initializerForParam).isNotPresent();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer.impl;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assumptions.assumeThatCode;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.willReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

class RolesParamInitializerTest {
    private final RolesParamInitializer initializer = new RolesParamInitializer();

    @Test
    void testExtractValuesFromAuthentication() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = List.of(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin")
        );
        Authentication authenticationMock = mock(Authentication.class);
        willReturn(roles).given(authenticationMock).getAuthorities();

        Collection<?> paramValues = initializer.extractValuesFromAuthentication(authenticationMock);

        assertThat(paramValues.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(paramValues).asList().containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(roles);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetParamValues() {
        String userString = "user", admingString = "admin";
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = List.of(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userString),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(admingString)
        );
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                null, null, roles
        );
        ServerWebExchange exchangeMock = mock(ServerWebExchange.class);
        given(exchangeMock.getPrincipal()).willReturn(Mono.just(authentication));

        assumeThatCode(() -> {
            Collection<?> paramValues = initializer.extractValuesFromAuthentication(authentication);
            assertThat(paramValues.size()).isEqualTo(2);
            assertThat(paramValues).asList().containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(roles);
        }).doesNotThrowAnyException();

        StepVerifier.create(initializer.getParamValues(exchangeMock).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast))
                .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
                .expectNextCount(2)
                .expectRecordedMatches(recordedRoles ->
                        recordedRoles.containsAll(roles) &&
                                roles.containsAll(recordedRoles))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.service.paramInitializer.impl;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.Collection;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assumptions.assumeThatCode;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

class PrincipalParamInitializerTest {
    private final PrincipalParamInitializer initializer = new PrincipalParamInitializer();
    private final String principalName = "mickey";

    @Test
    void testExtractValuesFromAuthentication() {
        Authentication authenticationMock = mock(Authentication.class);
        given(authenticationMock.getName()).willReturn(principalName);

        Collection<?> paramValues = initializer.extractValuesFromAuthentication(authenticationMock);

        assertThat(paramValues.size()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(paramValues.iterator().next()).isEqualTo(principalName);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetParamValues() {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principalName, null);
        ServerWebExchange exchangeMock = mock(ServerWebExchange.class);
        given(exchangeMock.getPrincipal()).willReturn(Mono.just(authentication));

        assumeThatCode(() -> {
            Collection<?> paramValues = initializer.extractValuesFromAuthentication(authentication);
            assertThat(paramValues.size()).isEqualTo(1);
            assertThat(paramValues.iterator().next()).isEqualTo(principalName);
        }).doesNotThrowAnyException();

        StepVerifier.create(initializer.getParamValues(exchangeMock).map(String::valueOf))
                .expectNext(principalName)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.testUtil;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

public class RouteBuilderUtil {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<GatewayFilter> getFilters(Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder) {
        return (List<GatewayFilter>) getAbstractBuilderField(routeBuilder, "gatewayFilters");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
    private static Object getAbstractBuilderField(Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder, String fieldName) {
        return getAbstractBuilderField(routeBuilder, fieldName, Object.class);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private static <T> T getAbstractBuilderField(Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder, String fieldName, Class<T> clazz) {
        Field gatewayFilters = routeBuilder.getClass()
                .getSuperclass()
                .getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        gatewayFilters.setAccessible(true);
        return clazz.cast(gatewayFilters.get(routeBuilder));
    }

    public static URI getUri(Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder) {
        return getAbstractBuilderField(routeBuilder, "uri", URI.class);
    }
}
```

## Appendix

It's not for review, but I decided to include these snippets so that you have a better understanding of the context in which `ParamInitializer`s are used. They are not supposed to compile, I'd have to include much more classes and likely to go beyond the character limit. Here's where `ParamInitializers` is used

```java
@Configuration
public class RouteAssemblerConfig {
// more RouteAssemblers
    @Bean
    public EndpointRouteAssembler paramInitializingRouteAssembler(ParamInitializers paramInitializers) {
        return (routeInConstruction, endpoint) -> {
            for (EndpointParameter param : endpoint.getDetails().getParameters()) {
                Optional<ParamInitializer> optionalParamInitializer = paramInitializers.findInitializerForParam(param);
                optionalParamInitializer.ifPresent(
                        paramInitializer -> paramInitializer.addInitializingFilter(routeInConstruction)
                );
            }
            return routeInConstruction;
        };
    }
```

`RouteAssembler`s incrementally build a `Route` from a collected endpoint. When a new application is found in the Eureka cache, its Open API is fetched, parsed, and its endpoints are made into `Route`s like this (I made a few simplifications in this explanation, but that's the overall flow of Dynamic Gateway)

```java
// DynamicRouteLocator

    private Route transformToRoute(DocumentedEndpoint<?> documentedEndpoint) {
        Route.AsyncBuilder routeBuilder = Route.async();
        for (EndpointRouteAssembler assembler : endpointRouteAssemblers) {
            routeBuilder = assembler.process(routeBuilder, documentedEndpoint);
        }
        return routeBuilder.build();
    }
```